# Is it possible to have separate cookie caches per webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control

If you were to login to a website with a webbrowser control, then (using another webbrowser control, in the same program) navigated to the same website, I would be logged into that website because in the first control I logged in.

Is there a way to separate this so that each webbrowser could be logged into different accounts?

The website *only* uses cookies to store who you are logged in as. IPs and whatnot are ignored.

Comment: Not possible, answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051365/multiple-webbrower-sessions-processes-in-one-window). You'd need to have separate processes, or manage your session state without cookies (e.g., via a URL parameter).